# Creation of a dropdown list that displays a result view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I don't do ios development full time and I'm just getting into it to design my app.  I have gotten to a point where I need to take a custom type ahead dropdown (I already have this working and populating from firebase in a view controller) and display a scrollable list of results based off the selection in the dropdown.  Basically they will be selecting county and as a result all the document requests relating to that county will be displayed (firebase where query).  I would also like to make each document request selectable and have a document request detail screen where they would upload the document for the document request.  How would I go about doing this?  I have read about TableviewControllers but I don't know if its possible to have a custom type ahead dropdown inside of one?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found the answer to this after a couple of weeks of experimenting.  If anybody needs it post up in here.